# Formula across objects

Tags: formula

I have a custom object "Reporting__c".

This custom object is linked to MyContracts__c, which is a child of Opportunity.

I need to display a field from Opportunity on my Reporting__c object and I want to use a formula.

I tried:

```
Formula(Text) = MyContracts__r.Opportunity.CustomField
```

But this does not work. Isn't this possible?  Tia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm suprised you didn't get an error from that seeing how your lookup to your Opportunity is a custom field. Either click edit or go back to your definition of your formula and switch over to the tab called advance formula.

[image]

Click on insert and it should make your life a lot easier.

[image]

And finally insert.

[image]

Your final formula should look something like this:
**Opportunity__r.FIELD_API_NAME**

Answer (score 1):

Since MyContracts__c is a custom object, your opportunity field will also be a custom object, Opportunity__c. Try appending __r to the Opportunity field in your formula, like this

```
MyContracts__r.Opportunity__r.CustomField
```

Relationships for standard fields won't need __r, but you'll always have to put it for custom fields (even if the custom field points to a standard object).